# No implementation found for method dispose for just_audio Flutter plugin on Android TV devices

Tags: android, flutter, android-tv, just-audio

I have a Flutter app on Android phones and TV devices. I am using two `just_audio` players to play music and sound effects, respectively.

My dispose code looks like this:

```
 @override
  dispose() {
    try {
      _timer?.cancel(); //stop the timer
      WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
      _controller.dispose(); //disp[ose controller playing animations
      WakelockPlus.disable(); //disable wake lock
      _soundPlayer.dispose(); //dispose just_audio player #1
      _musicPlayer.dispose(); //dispose just_audio player #2
    } catch (ex, st) {
      FirebaseCrashlytics.instance
          .recordError(ex, st, reason: 'workoutDispose');
    }
    super.dispose();
  }
```

This works in vast majority of cases, but occassionally I get a report in Firebase Crashlytics that the app has crashed in production with below error. I cannot reproduce the error and thus cannot file a bug on GitHub.

```
Fatal Exception: io.flutter.plugins.firebase.crashlytics.FlutterError: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method dispose on channel com.ryanheise.just_audio.methods.36090486-58da-44d3-9ca0-f1f29e063203)
#00 pc 0x891c6f com.example.app (MethodChannel._invokeMethod [platform_channel.dart:320]) (BuildId: 3aa6f915bd6b94591e48b711e1f3fe18)
#01 pc 0x8a201f com.example.app (MethodChannelAudioPlayer.dispose [method_channel_just_audio.dart:174]) (BuildId: 3aa6f915bd6b94591e48b711e1f3fe18)
#02 pc 0x87400f com.example.app (AudioPlayer._disposePlatform [just_audio.dart:1494]) (BuildId: 3aa6f915bd6b94591e48b711e1f3fe18)
#03 pc 0x888937 com.example.app (AudioPlayer.dispose [just_audio.dart:1204]) (BuildId: 3aa6f915bd6b94591e48b711e1f3fe18)
```

The code referenced in the error message looks like this:

```
  /// Release all resources associated with this player. You must invoke this
  /// after you are done with the player.
  Future<void> dispose() async {
    if (_disposed) return;
    _disposed = true;
    if (_nativePlatform != null) {
      await _disposePlatform(await _nativePlatform!); //<== this line fails
      _nativePlatform = null;
    } //etc...
```

I am not sure what `_disposePlatform` does and why is it ending up causing an unhandled error even though it is in try/catch block (perhaps something to do with async call without await?).

This is happening on Android TV and Chromecast devices. Not every time. I have a Chromecast I use for testing and am unable to reproduce this error. There are also many TV users out there, the error happens very infrequently.

I also used to get it for Sdk_goog3_x86_64 device which I believe is Google's play store testing device, but that seems to have stopped, so lately it is only TVs.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Since the plugin itself is crashing you should submit a bug report on GitHub.